# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown reserved key '_typeConverter'

Tags: struts2, upgrade, illegalargumentexception, ognl

I am getting the below error while I am trying to login to my Struts application. This is occurring after upgrading my Struts libraries to latest.

Please share any information which will help me fix this. Previous version of Struts was 2.3.10. The newer version is 2.5.10.1.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown reserved key
 '_typeConverter'
     at ognl.OgnlContext.put(OgnlContext.java:536)
     at ognl.Ognl.setTypeConverter(Ognl.java:346)
     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.setProperty(OgnlUtil.java:225)
     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlReflectionProvider.setProperty(OgnlReflectionProvider.java:90)
     at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsResultFactory.setParameter(StrutsResultFactory.java:67)
     at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsResultFactory.setParameters(StrutsResultFactory.java:52)
     at org.apache.struts2.factory.StrutsResultFactory.buildResult(StrutsResultFactory.java:41)
     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildResult(ObjectFactory.java:220)
     at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:215)
>     ... 18 more
```

Comment: You should post also some code so we can have a context for this error

Comment: Thank you @rakwaht for the comment. I don't know which of the code is throwing the error too. This is like an application level error. Before opening any page on the screen this error is showing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong version of the OGNL library. Use Maven or equivalent to manage dependencies. Or download [Essential Dependencies Only](http://www-us.apache.org/dist/struts/2.5.10.1/struts-2.5.10.1-min-lib.zip) to see which version of the OGNL you need to use with the Struts 2.5.10.1.

Comment: Reserver word is in all versions OGNL. This answer is wrong.

Comment: @RomanC Where from it comes then? You don't know what you're talking about. You can try it yourself to see I'm right.

Comment: Thank you @AleksandrM for the answer. I tried the OGNL jar file you gave. It looks like it worked. I am not seeing that exception anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have used reserved key `_typeConverter`. Rename your key to something else.

```
 RESERVED_KEYS.put(TYPE_CONVERTER_CONTEXT_KEY, null);
```

This code from apidocs for [`OgnlContext`](https://commons.apache.org/dormant/commons-ognl/apidocs/org/apache/commons/ognl/OgnlContext.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Roman C. I couldn't see _typeConverter key in my entire code base.

Comment: @ramanareddy438 Did you see the link I've posted? It's a codedebase that you use.